# Parameterized post-Newtonian formalism of Newtonian mechanics

Tags: post-newtonian

Please kindly advise why the parameters $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are both zero for classical Newtonian mechanics (see attached screenshot of Wikipedia (the page about Binet's equation)) instead of $\gamma = -1$, $\beta = 0$ such that it complies with the ordinary $F = - \frac{G M m}{r^{2}}$ equation. Is it coming from any relativistic (special) correction on the masses and distances?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: *why the parameters gamma and beta are both zero for classical Newtonian mechanics?* They’re [defined that way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_post-Newtonian_formalism#Beta-delta_notation).

Comment: Note that for classical Newtonian mechanics $c=\infty$, so the $h/rc$ term vanishes for all values of $\gamma$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ghoster ! The infinite c is the aha moment for me.